# Plot Times Series of Sentiment by Company in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, axis

I would like to make a sentiment analysis in R.
In have a dataset with a column "Svolume" with values as 1,5,41,...
Another column with different names of company.
A last column with the dates yyyy-mm-dd.

I would like to plot the times series by dates for each company, So If I have 3 company, I would like to have 3 lines, on the x axis the dates, and y axis the svolumes.

I wrote this :

```
data2=data[order(as.Date(data$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
```

In order to order the data by dates.

```
plot.ts(data2$Svolume)
axis(1,1:40,data2$Date)
```

And then this to plot a time serie of the Svolumes and then to put the dates on the X axis. I have two problems: I have only one line so I can't see the difference between the 3 company (I would love to have the line of the total too if possible), and my second problem is that it's impossible to read the dates as there are horizontal and so are wrote one on each others. Is there a way to write dates verticaly for example in order to read it?

I would like to have a plot like this: [times series plot 1](https://www.google.ie/search?q=time%20series%20plot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIiY_yj8TaxgIV6JzbCh3Yew8H&biw=1304&bih=697#imgdii=BNrDogjorCRitM%3A%3BBNrDogjorCRitM%3A%3B_rNvRM_-KEd3TM%3A&imgrc=BNrDogjorCRitM%3A) but instead of "websites" have the "volumes" and instead of "shoes,socks,lace" have the name of my companies/subjects

Or like that but with the svolumes [time series plot 2](https://www.google.ie/search?q=time%20series%20plot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIiY_yj8TaxgIV6JzbCh3Yew8H&biw=1304&bih=697#imgdii=BuZU2JR5Pkv5DM%3A%3BBuZU2JR5Pkv5DM%3A%3BCWCRZ9lxygOKdM%3A&imgrc=BuZU2JR5Pkv5DM%3A)

That's how my data looks like:

```
> head(data)
            Date Time Subject  Sscore  Smean Svscore Sdispersion Svolume  Sbuzz    Last close
1 2015-07-08 09:10:00     MMM -0.2280 0.2593 -0.2795       0.375       8 0.6026 155.430000000
2 2015-07-08 09:10:00     ACE -0.4415 0.3521 -0.0374       0.500       4 0.7200 104.460000000
3 2015-07-07 09:10:00     AES  1.9821 0.0233  1.1743       1.000       1 1.9445  13.200000000
4 2015-07-04 09:10:00     AFL -2.9335 0.0035 -0.2975       1.000       1 0.8321  61.960000000
5 2015-07-07 09:10:00     MMM  0.2977 0.2713 -0.7436       0.400       5 0.4895 155.080000000
6 2015-07-07 09:10:00     ACE -0.2331 0.3519 -0.1118       1.000       3 0.7196 103.330000000
         Company name       Date
1          3M Company 2015-07-08
2         ACE Limited 2015-07-08
3 The AES Corporation 2015-07-07
4          AFLAC Inc. 2015-07-04
5          3M Company 2015-07-07
6         ACE Limited 2015-07-07
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it, if it can help someone else:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data)+geom_line(aes(x=data$Date, y=data$Svolume,
+ group=data$Subject, color=data$Subject))
```

Comment: Well done. Just to save some typing, you can write it like this: `ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=volume, group=Subject, color=Subject))` (i.e. without the `data$`) and ggplot will read the column names from `data`.